# Not working Butterknife with null pointer exception error

Tags: android, butterknife

I am trying to use `ButterKnife` within my Android project.

I have an `Activity` that implements an `Interface`. I am using MVP pattern. 
I am trying to get text from the `EditText` but it throws a

> null pointer exception.

Here is my simple code.

**Gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
```

**Layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rao.myapplication.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUseName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUseName"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:onClick="loginClick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassword"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
 package com.example.rao.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rao.myapplication.Presenter.LoginActivityPresenter;
import com.example.rao.myapplication.View.LoginActivityView;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginActivityView {

    @BindView(R.id.etUseName)
    EditText userNameET;

    @BindView(R.id.etPassword)
    EditText passwordET;

    @BindView(R.id.btnLogin)
    Button loginBtn;

    private LoginActivityPresenter presenter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        passwordET.setText("abcd"); // Fails here as well
        presenter = new LoginActivityPresenter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void navigateToListActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void loginFailed() {

    }

    public void loginClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, userNameET.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); // Fails here
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}
```

**Here is the error log**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.example.rao.myapplication, PID: 24847
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.rao.myapplication/com.example.rao.myapplication.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                          at com.example.rao.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Could you please guide me in the right direction on this, please.

Comment: Post your LoginActivityView class also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**add below line also in your gradle file....**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.+'//add this line also
```

**Hope it solve your problems....**

Comment: Have the same issue, but this doesn't solve it. Any other solution?

Comment: @sushildlh I am facing the same issue even after adding above two dependencies in my build.gradle

Comment: this is only solution for gradle

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the gradle file and check.
Here is the link for [official documentation.](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

**GRADLE**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you forgot to add `ButterKnife.bind(this);` after setContentView, you will get NullPointerException.